# Why do anonymous objects sometimes require a default constructor?

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

If I write the following program, it works as I expect:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo (std::string x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
};

int main () { Foo("hello, world"); }
```

However, if I write a slightly different program, I get a compilation error:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo (std::string x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
};

std::string x("hello, world");

int main () { Foo(x); }
```

The error is:

> `prog.cc: In function 'int main()':`
> `prog.cc:10:20: error: no matching function for call to 'Foo::Foo()'`

[The complete error can be seen on IDEONE.](http://ideone.com/lWhOXH)

**Why does the error occur for the second program and not the first?**

Comment: hint: http://ideone.com/BVMI8z

Comment: Moved this comment out of one answer, since it's apparently in _both_.  This is another argument for C++11's [uniform initialization](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init).

Comment: @MooingDuck: Thanks, I forgot about the "redundant parentheses" rule for declarations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have declared a variable `x` with type `Foo`

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(){}
    Foo (std::string x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
    void test(){ std::cout << "test" << std::endl; };
};

std::string x("hello, world");

int main () { Foo(x); x.test(); }
```

[print "test"](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b3b65151e36cb46)

---

What you want is use uniform initialization syntax `Foo{x}`

```
struct Foo {
    Foo (std::string x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
};

std::string x("hello, world");

int main () { Foo{x}; }
```

[print "hello, world"](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/655769db9ce18de6)

Comment: Can you explain why `Foo a("a"), {x};` doesn't work?

Comment: @jxh what do you expect from it? `a` initialized with `"a"` and what? same reason you can have `int a(1), 2;`, you need to give a name for second object.

Comment: I am trying to create the anonymous temporary after the `,`.

Comment: @jxh it just not valid C++ syntax.

Comment: @jxh: How to do that would be an interesting SO question.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Except that it serves no real purpose, as I have no use case in mind.

Answer (score 8):

`Foo(x);` means the same as `Foo x;` . You can add redundant parentheses to the name of the variable.

So you need the default constructor because this is creating a variable `x` with no arguments being passed to constructor.

You can workaround this by doing `Foo{x};` in C++11.

The parsing rule is that if something could be a valid declaration and a valid non-declaration statement, then it is in fact a declaration. See also [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/most-vexing-parse)

Comment: "workaround"? No no no! It's the solution! It should be done for everything! Brace initialization is great! :-)

Comment: @MarkGarcia it seems to have its ups and downs... eg. `vector<string> x{{"a", "b", "c"}};` is OK, but `vector<string> x{{"a", "b"}};` causes undefined behaviour!

Comment: @Deduplicator, Not that I know of with the semicolon there.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, And using single braces works for both :) I think brace-initialization is great when you know what to look out for.

Comment: @chris: Please elaborate. What's wrong with a simple cast?

Comment: @Deduplicator, As far as I know, `Type(identifier);` is always a declaration. `Type(identifier)` without the semicolon is a functional-style cast. Unfortunately, the plot thickens when `identifier` is replaced with `expression`. If you have a previous `x`, `Type(x);` is still a declaration. `Type(2);` is not. Even having a global `x` and doing `Type(::x);` fails to compile.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `Type(::x);` ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb, No clue.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, It turns out `Type(::x);` compiles with GCC 4.9. I [asked a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623071/is-typex-valid).

Answer (score -1):

I completely agree with above solution. Though this will still work:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo (string x) 
    { 
        cout << x << endl; 
    }
};


int main () 
{ 
    string x = "hello, world";
    Foo * abc = new Foo(x); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with OP's question

Comment: I have just told a way by which we can still use the existing class definition of Foo.

Comment: Implicitly suggesting `using namespace std` and providing sample code with a memory leak, what an example!