# Is Type(::x); valid?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, expression, declaration, language-lawyer

While [discussing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622472/why-do-anonymous-objects-sometimes-require-a-default-constructor#comment38158615_24622522) the `Type(identifier);` syntax and how it's a declaration, I came across `Type(::x);` not working with Clang. I would expect that given a global variable `x`, it would treat `::x` as an expression (`::x + 2` works) and cast `::x` to `Type`. However, it gives a compiler error.

Here is [a short example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb8132793645d00c):

```
int x;

int main() {
    int(::x); //does not compile
    int(::x + 2); //compiles
}
```

The compiler error given by Clang 3.5 is:

> error: definition or redeclaration of 'x' cannot name the global scope

GCC 4.9.0, however, compiles this just fine. Is this code valid or not?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is covered by [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `8.3` *Meaning of declarators* paragraph *6* which says (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> ( D1 )
>
> the type of the contained declarator-id is the same as that of the contained declarator-id in
>   the declaration
>
> T D1
>
> Parentheses do not alter the type of the embedded declarator-id, but they can alter the binding of complex
>   declarators.

so:

```
int(::x);
```

is equivalent to:

```
int ::x ;
```

which is clearly not valid, and this produces the same error as well. So `gcc 4.9` is not correct here but since this looks fixed in the `gcc 4.8.3` which was released later I would expect this to be fixed in later releases of `4.9` as well. Although I don't see any obvious matches for this issue in the [gcc 4.8.3 bugs fixed list](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=RESOLVED&resolution=FIXED&target_milestone=4.8.3) but they don't claim it is a complete list.

The second case is a functional explicit type conversion which is covered in section `5.2.3` *Explicit type conversion (functional notation)* which says:

> A simple-type-specifier (7.1.6.2) or typename-specifier (14.6)
>   followed by a parenthesized expression-list constructs a value of the
>   specified type given the expression list. If the expression list is a
>   single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent (in
>   definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the corresponding cast
>   expression (5.4).[...]

This is unambiguous since `::x + 2` is an *expression*.

The section that covers when a statement is considered a declaration or a expression is `6.8` *Ambiguity resolution* which says:

> There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving expression-statements
>   and declarations: An expressionstatement with a function-style
>   explicit type conversion (5.2.3) as its leftmost subexpression can be
>   indistinguishable from a declaration where the first declarator starts
>   with a (. **In those cases the statement is a declaration.** [ Note: To
>   disambiguate, the whole statement might have to be examined to
>   determine if it is an expression-statement or a declaration. This
>   disambiguates many examples.

and provides the following examples:

> ```
> T(a)->m = 7; // expression-statement
> T(a)++; // expression-statement
> T(a,5)<<c; // expression-statement
> T(*d)(int); // declaration
> T(e)[5]; // declaration
> T(f) = { 1, 2 }; // declaration
> T(*g)(double(3)); // declaration
> ```

Note: without the `()` then `T ::D` is a *qualified-id* in the case of `T` being a *class*, that is a covered in the grammar of `5.1` *Primary expressions*.

**Update**

Filed a [gcc bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62116).

gcc's response is that:

> Current G++ and EDG both treat it as the valid expression (int)::x

Since this response implies `clang` is incorrect(*I don't agree though*), I filed a [clang bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22633) and [older bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=4594) looks similar and seems to disagree with the `gcc` response.

**Update 2**

In response to the `clang bug report` Richard Smith agrees this should be treated as a declaration and says:

> That does not imply clang is incorrect; in fact, Clang is correct
>   here, as far as I can see. (I've also sent a bug report to EDG.)
>
> That said, we should give a proper 'you hit a vexing parse, here's how
>   to disambiguate' error in this case.

**Update 3**

`gcc` [confirms](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62116#c4) it is a bug.

Comment: Do you know of the part that says this must be treated as a declaration rather than an expression regardless of the declaration being invalid? P.S., the error *does* change if `struct Foo {};` is used as a type :)

Comment: "In a **declaration** T D" (emphasis mine). We have to establish that `int (::x);` is a declaration before this clause can be applined.

Comment: `Foo::x;` and `Foo (::x);` give different errors, where `Foo` is a class.

Comment: @MattMcNabb that is because in the `Foo ::x` case the space is removed and it is treated as a qualified id.

Comment: But your post says `T (D1)` is equivalent to `T D1`. Set `T` as `Foo` and `D1` as `::x`. This seems to reinforce my contention that your first quote only applies to something which has already been established to be a declaration.

Comment: I followed the standard in what exactly a declaration was and indeed `int(::x);` counts as a declaration.

Comment: @chris can you post an answer detailing that?

Comment: This whole line of reasoning seems fishy; if we have `template<typename T> void func() {  T (::x); }` it should not make a difference to the parsing whether `T` is `int` or `Foo`

Comment: @MattMcNabb, It's a long chain, but not answer-worthy with these ones here tbh. I'll put it in a comment when I finish.

Comment: @chris it seems to me that the crux of the matter is whether `int (::x);` is syntactically valid as a declaration or not. The other answers don't address this other than to assert its truthfulness

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Of course it also sucks when you forget exactly which path led you there.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Here's the sequence I found: http://pastebin.com/sh5fuuX5. That's for `int(::x);`, but can be branched a bit for others I guess.

Comment: @chris I made a mistake, it is a `qualified-id` without the `()` when `T` is a class.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Feel free to use that how you wish as well. It's really too late for me to start creating anything.

Comment: With the reassurance from that Pastebin link that `Type(::x);` is indeed a valid `declaration-statement`, I feel this answer best explains why the declaration is chosen and what's going on. While I'm sure more could be said about `T(::x);` vs `T ::x;`, that really wasn't the question. Thanks.

Comment: @MattMcNabb fyi, gcc confirmed this is a bug

Comment: _"Since this response implies clang is incorrect"_ If I had meant to imply that I would have closed the PR rather than leave it unconfirmed :-) What I meant is that `(int)::x` is a valid expression, and GCC and EDG (rightly or wrongly) treat your example as equivalent to that. Richard convinced me that is wrong.

Comment: @JonathanWakely apologies, I misinterpreted. It makes sense now that you explain it that way ;-)

Answer (score 11):

This looks like the most vexing parse to me. If it can be parsed as a declaration it will be. The first could be parsed as a declaration of an int variable (`int ::x;`), but the `::` is illegal in that context. The second *has* to be an expression and so the compiler does the math, casts it to int, and throws away the result.

Was this a pedantic question, or is there another problem as well? If you have a specific problem you're trying to solve, additional information would allow a workaround for your use case.

Comment: @Matt McNabb That's just the way the C++ language works. It's the same sort of reason we need the `typename` keyword for templates.

Comment: I'm unclear on what `int::x;` is supposed to be. `Foo::x;` would look up `x` in the scope of `Foo`, and this is not a declaration. It seems that `int::x;` is different to `int(::x);`

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize an invalid declaration still applied with a valid expression.

Comment: @MarkB We need `typename` to indicate whether an identifier identifies a type or a variable. I don't see how that is similar to the case `int (::x);` . The rule is that if it is *syntactically* valid as a declaration then it is a declaration (even if it's also ill-formed as a declaration). However I don't see how `int (::x);` (at block scope) is valid syntax for a declaration.