# Cannot pass std::cout to ostream& constructor

Tags: c++, cout

I tried to create generic stream class holder, but it seems like I cannot pass `std::cout` to it, the code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct x
{
    std::ostream &o;
    x(std::ostream &o):o(o){}
};

int main()
{
    x(std::cout);
    x.o<<"Hi\n";
    return 0;
}
```

fails when compiled as:

```
c++ str.cc -o str -std=c++11
str.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
str.cc:11:14: error: invalid use of qualified-name ‘std::cout’
str.cc:12:4: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
```

Why?

Comment: Did you mean `x someName(std::cout); someName.o << ...`?

Comment: The reasoning for why that first line is an error should be the same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623071/is-typex-valid. You can't use `x` like an object afterward anyway, though. `x.o` makes no sense since `x` is a type.

Comment: As chris points out the answer that explains why it does not work but this looks like a typo as @Angew indicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x(std::cout);
```

is equivalent to

```
x std::cout;
```

which tries to declare a local variable called `std::cout`. That's not allowed.

If you wanted to declare a variable of type `x`, passing `std::cout` to its constructor, then that's

```
x x(std::cout);
```

although, for the sake of your sanity, it might be better to give it a different name to the class (and change the following line to use that name).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
int main()
{
    x object(std::cout);
    object.o << "Hi\n";
    return 0;
}
```