# Visual Studio C++ compiler weird behaviour

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, most-vexing-parse

I'm just curious to know why this small piece of code compiles correctly (and without warnings) in *Visual Studio*. Maybe the result is the same with [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) and [Clang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang), but unfortunately I can't test them now.

```
struct T {
    int t;
    T() : t(0) {}
};

int main() {
    T(i_do_not_exist);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: extremly interesting! the most WTF compiler bug I have ever seen!

Comment: also *int(i_do_not_exist)* works fine, but with undefined variable warning

Comment: It also compiles with g++: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8dd5a50af7c888d

Comment: See a similar question: [Is Type(::x); valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24623071/1708801)

Comment: @DavidHaim this is not a bug

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622472/why-do-anonymous-objects-sometimes-require-a-default-constructor

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`T(i_do_not_exist);` is an object declaration with the same meaning as `T i_do_not_exist;`.

N4567 § 6.8[stmt.ambig]p1

> There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving *expression-statement*s and *declaration*s: An *expression-statement* with a function-style explicit type conversion (5.2.3) as its leftmost subexpression can be indistinguishable from a *declaration* where the ﬁrst *declarator* starts with a `(`. In those cases the *statement* is a *declaration*.

§ 8.3[dcl.meaning]p6

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
>
> `( D1 )`
>
> the type of the contained *declarator-id* is the same as that of the contained *declarator-id* in the declaration
>
> `T D1`
>
> Parentheses do not alter the type of the embedded *declarator-id*, but they can alter the binding of complex declarators.

Comment: I sometimes hate C++... like just now.

Comment: That's why one should use list initialization `T{i_do_not_exist}` which gives a compiler error.

Comment: Can someone clarify: is this an instance of a "most vexing parse" problem or something unrelated?

Comment: @user10607 how about we call it "slightly vexing parse"? It could be "vexing" because it's ambiguous, but it is less vexing than the traditional "most vexing" `T func( U(x), U(y) );` , and perhaps also less vexing than the "somewhat vexing parse"  `T func();`

Answer (score 17):

Because it defines a variable of type T:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d420870b1a6490d7

```
#include <iostream>

struct T {
    int t;
    T() : t(0) {}
};

int main() {
    T(i_do_not_exist);
    i_do_not_exist.t = 120;
    std::cout << i_do_not_exist.t;
    return 0;
}
```

The above example looks silly, but this syntax is allowed for a reason.

A better example is:

```
int func1();
namespace A
{
   void func1(int);
   struct X {
       friend int (::func1)();
   };
}
```

Probably other examples could be found.